# Min/max for highstock chart

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to set min/max yAxis parameters for this stockchart?

https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume

Here fiddle for this example:

`example`
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume/

I tried, but it not works.

Comment: it is possible to change yAxis.min and yAxis.max for this chart. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hveh6yqp/

Comment: And i must set startOnTick: false?

Comment: With startOnTick: true your axis may be forced to start on tick that is automatically calculated. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.startOnTick